# What is the relationship between a tangent line and the sector length created by a line originating outside the circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

I am trying to find a general relationship between a tangent line and a sector length.

The setup could be equated to a circle with its center at (0,-r) such that the topmost point of the circle is at the origin. There is a line originating at some point (0,h) which is angled downward to hit the circle at some point. This line is not guaranteed to be tangential to the circle. I want to figure out the general relationship between the length of the horizontal line (defined from (0,0) to the X-Intercept) and the Sector length (defined by the distance along the circumference from (0,0) to the point of intersection).

[image: geometry diagram]

My gut instinct is that the relationship is a trigonometric relationship which relies on the ratio of the height ‘h’ and the radius ‘r’. It is fairly easy to find the Angle between the origin and a tangent point given h and r, as it is arcsin(r/(r+h)). Then the arc angle is the difference between that and 90. And I know that the ratio is 1:1 at the origin because the length for both is zero. I’ve played with a bunch of values and looked for some relationships but I’m struggling to make any progress here. And I can’t seem to find similar setups online.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/lmLtLPJ

Comment: Just **a** general relationship? Here's one: $GE \le GD$. No trigonometry required. For a more helpful answer, you should probably state what it is you actually want to accomplish with "a general relationship"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the distance $GE$ be denoted by $a$. What can you tell about the angle $GAE$, in terms of $a$ and $h$? You can then use the cosine rule to determine the length $AD$, and then apply it again to determine the angle $GCB$. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: That helps immensely as I had forgotten about Law of Sines and Law of Cosines. It looks like I can use law of sines to solve the angle ADC, and from there just subtract the sum of ADC and GAE from 180 to get the central angle and from there calculate the sector length. Thank you!

Comment: @Arland Of course, law of sines is more efficient here than law of cosines. Good job! We got there together :)